# What is the AngularJS equivalent of a JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

### Background

I created a node module called [shotgun](http://github.com/chevex/shotgun) and another called [shotgun-client](http://github.com/chevex/shotgun) which when combined provide a node-powered realtime terminal API in the browser. The client library let's the user create an instance of `shotgun.ClientShell` and exposes an API to talk to the server. This `clientShell` instance is just an API with methods on it which means the user has to do all the work of creating an interface that uses that API.

I wanted to give the user a shortcut so I created [this awesome JQuery plugin](https://gist.github.com/chevex/8876220) that acts as a wrapper for the `clientShell` object and creates a simple HTML terminal interface for the user.

Demo: http://codetunnel.com/demos/shotgun

### The JQuery plugin does the following...

1. Creates a bunch of elements and inserts them within the element the plugin was invoked on which would be `#console` if it was invoked like this:

   $('#console').shotgunConsole();
2. Instantiates an instance of the `shotgun.ClientShell` API.

   var clientShell = new shotgun.ClientShell(options);
3. Sets up event handlers to tie user actions to `clientShell` API calls.

### My Question

I am new to AngularJS and I'm curious how I would turn a JQuery plugin like this one into an AngularJS directive. Essentially I'd like to do this:

```
<div ng-shotgun-console></div>
```

Then I'd like that `div` to transform into the same HTML terminal that my JQuery plugin creates. I'm just really confused as to how I package that up so it can be included as an "Angular Adapter" alongside my "JQuery Adapter". JQuery plugins are easy and are pretty much entirely contained in a single function...

```
$.fn.shotgunConsole = function (options) { ... };
```

...but I can't figure out how to create a simple script that does the same things and could easily be dropped into someone's existing Angular application with the same ease as a JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular way to things like this is [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Here's an example of the directive for wiring custom jquery-powered autocomplete control:

```
angular
    .module('ng-button-autocomplete', [])
    .directive('ngButtonAutocomplete', function () { return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type="text"><button type="button" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button></div>',
        scope: {
            source: '&',
            value: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr) {
            var input = $($elem.children()[0]),
                button = $($elem.children()[1]);
            $scope.$watch('value', function (val) {
                input.val(val);
            });
            input.autocomplete({
                source: $scope.source(),
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.value = ui.item.value;
                    });
                },
                close: function () {
                    input.autocomplete('option', 'minLength', 9999);
                },
                minLength: 9999
            });
            button.click(function () {
                input.autocomplete('option', 'minLength', 0);
                input.autocomplete('search', input.val());
            });
        }
    };});
```

You then inject this module to your application like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-button-autocomplete']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.xs = ['abc', 'acd', 'bcd'];
    $scope.x = 123;
});
```

And just use directive in html like this:

```
<div ng-button-autocomplete data-source="xs" data-value="x"></div>
```

Comment: This is a wonderfully complete answer with an excellent example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Its rather simple to turn a plugin into a directive.  Here is a **basic example** assuming that your jQuery plugin is already loaded on the page.

HTML:

```
<div shotgun-console="options"></div>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.options = {
    // ... some options
}
```

Directive:

```
.directive('shotgunConsole',function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            shotgunConsole: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            $(elm).shotgunConsole(scope.options);
            scope.$watch('options',function(newOptions){
                // something to update the options
                $(elm).shotgunConsole(newOptions);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Oh interesting, using the actual JQuery plugin within the directive. I was going to write the directive from scratch and let the user include whichever adapter they wanted. But maybe I'll just include them both in the bundled script and do this extremely lightweight wrapper. It would keep the interface for the console in one place too instead of having to modify two adapters, but it also means the user needs JQuery on the page even if they only want the Angular adapter. I'll let you know what I choose :)

Comment: Just a side note, AngularJS recommends that jQuery be included on the page and loaded before AngularJS.  Its more, "optional to leave out" than "optional to include".  Glass half full kind of stuff lol.

Comment: Well right, I know that Angular will fall back on an internal implementation of JQuery lite if you don't include it on the page. However, I don't believe that lite version includes plugin functionality so in this configuration JQuery would have to be included in order to use the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Assuming your Angular application is assigned to "app":

```
app.directive('ngShotgunConsole', ['injectedDependency',
    function(injectedDependency) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: '/path/to/filename.html',
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.shotgunConsole();
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Using the link function in an Angular directive gives you access to element as if you were using jQuery. So "element" is like "$('your-selector')".